# How to make table from AJAX success a dataTable()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I have a library of dataTable() in some parts of my prototype website but without ajax function **Without ajax**

```
<table id = 'mytable'>
   //some content   
</table>
```

making table a datatable `$('#mytable').dataTable();` this method works and made the table a datatable

Here's how i applied it on using ajax

```
$.ajax({  
      url:"user.php",  
      method:"POST",  
      data:{id,id},  
      success:function(data) {  
           $(data).find('#usertable').dataTable();
            $('#myDiv').html(data);
          }
});
```

**sample.php**

```
$output .= '  
       <table id = "usertable">
              //some content
       </table>';

echo $output;
```

how can i make the ajax success response a datatable?

Comment: you can read the [docs](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) to do what you want in another way...it will be better than what you're trying to do I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the html to the dom first and create the datatable after that. You are doing it the other way arround. When you create the datatable, the html is not yet available in your dom and no datatable will be created.

```
$.ajax({  
    url: "user.php",  
    method: "POST",  
    data: {id: id},  
    success: function(data) {  
        $('#myDiv').html(data);        // Add html to the dom
        $('#myDiv table').dataTable();   // Create the datatable
    }
});
```

Comment: sir thank you for helping but this method is not working i tried it several time using your method still not making it a datatable

Comment: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined
    at Ja (jquery.dataTables.min.js:24)
    at N (jquery.dataTables.min.js:16)
    at HTMLTableRowElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:16)
    at jquery-1.12.4.js:142
    at Function.map (jquery-1.12.4.js:484)
    at jQuery.fn.init.map (jquery-1.12.4.js:141)
    at oa (jquery.dataTables.min.js:16)
    at e (jquery.dataTables.min.js:92)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:93)
    at Function.each (jquery-1.12.4.js:370)'

Comment: That's because you have an error in you html. A simple search on Google gave me this result: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/32575/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-dt-cellindex-of-undefined

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Ka (jquery.dataTables.min.js:23)
    at HTMLTableRowElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:16)
    at jquery-1.12.4.js:142
    at Function.map (jquery-1.12.4.js:484)
    at jQuery.fn.init.map (jquery-1.12.4.js:141)
    at oa (jquery.dataTables.min.js:16)
    at e (jquery.dataTables.min.js:92)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:93)
    at Function.each (jquery-1.12.4.js:370)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery-1.12.4.js:137)